# How can we make interesting projects with the Ada and the Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, ada

I am working with the raspberry pi3 around 4 months and it is working fine.Now i need to use Ada programming language with the Raspberry pi 3 for making interesting projects.Can any one push me to the wonderful world of the ARM and ADA?
**Note:**Don't suggest to use another programming language. I want to learn Ada and I have programming experiences with the languages like C,C++ and COBOL.

Comment: Where's the opinion-based part here?  There are only a limited number of Ada compilers targeting the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Ahh...  Well.  Which resources are good for learning Ada is definitely opinion based.  Maybe @Nekhil, maybe you should split the question, in one on Ada tooling for Raspberry Pi, and another one on learning resources for Ada.

Comment: Cobol for the Raspeberry Pi? Now, there's an idea ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Raspbian on your Raspberry Pi, you can install the FSF GNAT Ada compiler using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnat
```

For learning Ada, there is a good list of resources at [AdaIC](http://www.adaic.org/learn/).  Since you already know a bit of other languages, "Ada Distilled" may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, 
Train control using Ada on a Raspberry Pi: https://blog.adacore.com/train-control-using-ada-on-a-raspberry-pi
 Hope It's useful Thank you.

Comment: how can i contact you @chetan mahajan